# When launching electron app the content appears a bit shrunken then stretches going back to normal

Tags: javascript, electron

---

### I get this when I use :

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
   show: false,
});

mainWindow.once("ready-to-show", () => {
  mainWindow.show();
});
```

otherwise it's not happening!

by showing the window right away it appears normal!

app before the stretch:
[image: img of app before the stretch]

app after the stretch:
[image: img of app after the stretch]

Comment: can you post an image/gif of what you're seeing?

Comment: I added two images one before and another one after the stretch . thanks in advance (^_^)

Comment: I guess it's suspicious that showing the window in response to ready-to-show would cause this. I feel like there's something in your app that might be responsible for this. I haven't reproduced this in my own apps

Comment: yeah it's pretty suspicious , I checked the css  as well nothing appears to be off tho